# Change Title in Sharepoint Ribbon

Tags: ribbon

[image: Sahrepoint Ribbon]

In the above image i need to change the title "Sharepoint" in ribbon.
Is it possible to change?

If yes, then please let me know how to change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with SharePoint Management shell:

```
Set-SPSuiteBarBrandingElement -WebAppUrl http://sp2013.intranet.adventureworks.com -Text 'AdventureWorks Intranet'
```

Just replace the `AdventureWorks Intranet`with the text you want.

More details [here](http://sharepointryan.com/2013/04/16/customizing-the-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar-branding-using-powershell/)

Comment: Good to know Set-SPSuiteBarBrandingElement, seems "S" truncated from above command.

Comment: Oops, a typo there! I corrected it

Answer (score 2):

Yes,You can edit by modifying the ms-core-brandingText class by seattle.master
follow the steps given in below article to achieve the same.

http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-sharepoint-branding-text-in-the-upper-left-part-of-your-screen

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with PowerShell to.

```
$webApp = get-spwebApplication "http://yourWebapplicationUrl"
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "<div class='ms-core-brandingText'>Insert new title here</div>"
$webApp.Update()
```

Or you could change the text and create a link out of it. I've done this so users can just click the title and get back to the root site.

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://yourWebapplicationUrl"
$webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "<div class=""ms-core-brandingText""><a href="http://LinkUrl">Insert new title here</a></div>"
$webApp.Update()
```